# HTML input not hidding

Tags: html, types, input

I am not sure why this is not working I thought it should be but in chrome it is not hiding the input box

```
<input type="hidden" name="_id" id="_id" value="<?=$fetchretailer[0]['_id'];?>" readonly="readonly">
```

Could someone tell me if this is a bug, or if I have done something wrong.

here is the code above it

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="leadform">
    <form name="lead" id="lead">
        <input type="hidden" name="_id" id="_id" value="<?=$fetchretailer[0]['_id'];?>" />
```

Comment: Try closing the input tag: `<input ... />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably a missing quote in a tag above it.

Also, try removing the underscores from the name and ID attributes. That's not valid syntax. HTML attributes cannot start with underscores.